# Will operations and variables be created on top of the stack?

Tags: java, heap-memory, stack-memory

From what I understand from these link ([first link](http://net-informations.com/faq/net/stack-heap.htm) , [second link](https://www.journaldev.com/4098/java-heap-space-vs-stack-memory) , and [third link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UcPuWY0wn3w)) stack blocks will be created when there is method. However, what I am confused of is about the operations and int. Will they go on top of stack or not because i also read from this [web site](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html) about the operation of int add. The website state that "value1 and value2 must be of type int. values are popped from the operand stack. The int result is value1 + value2. The result is pushed onto the operand stack."

Assuming I have this type of code:

```
public static int bar (int x1, int x2, int x3, int x4, int x5, int x6, int x7, int x8, int x9, int x10, int x11, int x12, int x13, int x14, int x15, int x16, int x17, int x18, int x19, int x20){
int y = x1+x2+x3+x4+x5+x6+x7+x8+x9+x10+x11+x12+x13+x14+x15+x16+x17+x18+x19+x20; 
return y;
}
```

Does this means that the bar( ) stack block will be created as the most below, and then the 19 add operations are on top of the stack as well as the 20 integer? When I return the "y" variable, will the bar( ) method stack block will be popped? Please correct me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The *values* go onto the stack. The operators are in the instruction stream. Something like this:

```
PUSH x1
PUSH X2
; ADD adds the two top items on the stack, pops them, and pushes the result
ADD    ; now x1+x2 is on top of the stack
PUSH X3
ADD    ; now x1+x2+x2 is on top of the stack.
; etcetera
POP Y ; Stores the final sum into Y
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. Does that means that "x1+x2" is considered as a add( ) stack block and pushed on top of the bar( ) stack block? since I have 20 values, that means I have 19 add( ) stack blocks right? or will they pop at some point?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'stack block', but you can see from the pseudo-bytecode I posted that there are never more than two items on the stack in this case.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for the late reply. I understand what you meant already after you edited your answer. Also, I referred this link (http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~sinisa/courses/OSU/CS261/CS261_Textbook/Chapter06.pdf) for Activation Record Stack. It is similar to what you aswered right?